# Android PopupMenus

Tags: android, menu

I am looking for an easy popupmenu I could use for phones that operate on 2.3.3 and up.

Something like this, and works differently from a ContextMenu in that it doesn't require a listview:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try the following :

Create a file dialog.xml in your layout folder and add the following code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ErrorMsg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Do you want to un-install this app?" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/ErrorMsgDialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <Button android:id="@+id/Cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/Ok"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="OK" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and then in your class file use following code to display the dialog :

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
            R.layout.dialog, null);
    builder.setView(view);

    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

    Button cancel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Cancel);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    Button ok = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Ok);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do something here for OK action

        }
    });

    dialog.show();
```

Comment: As much as I like this, I would like it better if it used DialogFragments :-\

Comment: Will AlertDialog.Builder work with 2.3.3 Phones?  I do not believe so as Eclipse is forcing me to put @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the error ? like more information on the error string, line number where you are seeing the error.

Comment: the root element of your XML file needs to specify the android namespace with `xmlns` attribute

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is just create an AlertDialog.Builder object and configured its positive and negative buttons and then set the Title and the Messages and done. Removing the need for any layout files.